# Can I avoid a second object when using a unary operator on a temporary?

Tags: c++, c++20, copy-elision

The usual meaning of unary operators such as bitwise inversion, postfix increment, and unary minus is to return a modified copy of their argument.  When their argument is a temporary, is there a way to modify that original object, thus avoiding the creation and destruction of a second object?

The examples below both involve two objects:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct X {
  ~X()                    { cout << "destroy\n"; }
  X()                     { cout << "default construct\n"; }
  X(const X& )            { cout << "copy construct\n"; }
  X(      X&&)            { cout << "move construct\n"; }
  X& operator=(const X& ) { cout << "copy assign\n"; return *this; }
  X& operator=(      X&&) { cout << "move assign\n"; return *this; }
  X  operator~() const &  { cout << "~lvalue\n"; return *this; }
  X  operator~()       && { cout << "~rvalue\n"; return move(*this); }
};

int main(int, char**) {
  {
    cout << "Example 1\n";
    auto a = X();
    auto b = ~a;
  }
  {
    cout << "Example 2\n";
    auto a = ~X();
  }
}
```

I get this output (ignore that ~lvalue and copy construct "appear" out of order):

```
Example 1
default construct
~lvalue
copy construct
destroy
destroy
Example 2
default construct
~rvalue
move construct
destroy
destroy
```

Is there a way to rewrite the struct so that example 2 only creates and destroys a single object?

Comment: Sure, just return an rvalue reference from the `&&`-qualified `operator~`?

Comment: `X&& operator~() && { cout << "~rvalue\n"; return move(*this); }` also involves two objects when I execute that.

Comment: @KyleMarkley it's not possible. the temporary will be destroyed, you need to copy it to another object (`a` in the code).

Comment: what @HolyBlackCat said is a way, but it'd break `auto&& v = ~T{};`

Comment: You can have whatever behavior you want with your overloaded operators.  They do not have to return the traditional return type pattern — and sometimes that can be put to good effect (such as Boost Spirit X3) — but general guidance is to follow the lead of the traditional return type pattern. What you cannot change is their unary or binary nature, nor their operator precedence.

Comment: @KyleMarkley Because you create the second object in `main()`. It's not possible to elide this, at least not without C++23 passing `*this` by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to rewrite the struct so that example 2 only creates and destroys a single object?

But your code *says* to create two objects. You create a prvalue and then perform an operation on it which is *not* initializing some other object. That operation requires manifesting a temporary from that prvalue. That's object 1.

Then you use `auto a` to create a new object. That's object 2.

It doesn't matter what `operator~` is doing; you must manifest a temporary from the prvalue, since `operator~` needs to have a `this`. Even if the return value is a `&&` to `this` (which is *absolutely should not*, because `operator~` should be a `const` function), that wouldn't help, because `a` is a separate object. You can move construct `a`, but it won't ever not be a separate object.

If you only want one object, you have to use code that *says* to create only one object: `auto a = X(); a.invert();`.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly?
1) Object 1 is manifested as the (hidden) parameter of operator~.
2) Object 2 is created by the return.
3) The `auto a = ...` is elided (the returned object is a prvalue).
If operator~ returned a reference-to-self instead of an object, it's no longer a prvalue, so (3) can't elide.  This means I'm stuck: either the return or the initialization must create a new object.  There's no way for operator~ to return its (hidden) parameter.

Comment: @KyleMarkley: "*There's no way for operator~ to return its (hidden) parameter.*" There's no way to turn an lvalue back into a prvalue. Once you've manifested an object, it exists. As I said, your code explicitly asks to create 2 objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has some assumptions to justify the complication.

1. The object is generally expensive to copy (to justify the use of move),
2. The operation can be applied in-place without necessarily making a copy (otherwise we can just return the necessary copy always).
3. The in-place operation is at least somewhat cheaper than the corresponding out-of-place operation. (the "somewhat" is related to the cost of copying)

### The C++98 way

In this case, to first order, as @NicolBolas said, it is better to just give the user access to this in-place operation because it probably it is very useful even beyond your scenario.

In this case the class is fairly simple,

```
struct X {
    void tilde_inplace() { ... inplace operation ... }
};
```

and nothing else in regards of this hypothetical operation (which I didn't call `~` because it doesn't return a copy, as you indicated.)

usage:

```
auto x = X{};
x.tilde_inplace();
```

Very simple, no copies to worry about, no moves etc.
You can make a copy if you need to.

```
auto const x = X{};
auto x_copy = x; 
x_copy.tilde_inplace();
```

**This is very C++98 and it is fine.**

### Syntactic sugar/Functional interface

If one entertains the idea that for some reason one needs a "functional" interface to the operation one can do the following.
But remember that this is basically syntactic sugar... unless you really really need it for "generic programming" reasons:

```
struct X {
    void tilde_inplace() { ... inplace operation ... }
    X tilde() const { auto tmp = *this; tmp.tilde_inplace(); return tmp;}
};
```

This is an illustration of the assumption that at the end there is no other optimal way to do this other than in-place (otherwise `tilde()` can have an independent implementation).

### Robust (always work) solution

Extrapolating to exploit temporaries (rvalues):

```
struct X {
    void tilde_inplace() { ... inplace operation ... }
    X tilde() const& { auto tmp =           *this ; tmp.tilde_inplace(); return tmp; /*IF there is no better way*/}
    X tilde()     && { auto tmp = std::move(*this); tmp.tilde_inplace(); return tmp;}
};
```

This assumes very little about `X`, I think it is very robust.

One might be tempted to just remove `tmp` in the second case:

```
    X tilde()     && { this->tilde_inplace(); return *this;}
```

but, does it work? in the sense that it does elide the copy of `*this` with RVO). in all versions of C++11/14/17/20? I don't know.
Probably not.

To be sure the signature has to change to this more strange code:

```
    X&& tilde()     && { this->tilde_inplace(); return std::move(*this);}
```

Although this is the only case in which I managed to make the functional interface as lean as the C++98 interface (https://godbolt.org/z/EdP7KzzqM),
Arguably, I would say this doesn't correspond to the canonical signature of a *conventional* unary operator such as `operator~`, because it returns a reference.
("Arguably" because the canonical interface of operators is really only defined for build-ins. It is not clear what is the canonical generalization to classes.).

Another advantage of the "robust/uniform" solution is that it can be written as a single free or friend function.

```
struct X {
    void tilde_inplace() { ... inplace operation ... }
    auto free_tilde(X self) {self.tilde_inplace(); return self;}
};
```

See, no move or strange things in the implementation, `free_tilde` can be even `noexcept` if `tilde_inplace` is `noexcept`.
It is no coincidence that this trick is also used to implement an "always correct" copy assigment in terms of swap.

### Summary

So, in summary, for a robust solution, replace "`tilde`" by "`operator~`" above and you have the following recipe for your case.
Optionally hide the in-place interface (but there is nothing wrong with it unless there is a commitment to make classes immutable and to functional programming).

```
struct X {
 private:
    void tilde_inplace() { ... inplace operation ... }
 public:
    X operator~() const& { ... possibly out-of-place implementation if better at all, or copy + inplace }
    X operator~()     && { auto tmp = std::move(*this); tmp.tilde_inplace(); return tmp;}
};
```

so, I think this answers your question, if you have a temporary you can avoid a "second" object, from the perspective of the user and efficiency.

```
x = ~ std::move(x);
```

(But you were also able to do it without move, `x.tilde_inplace();` although in a non-functional paradigm).

Feel free to rebut this answer if you don't agree.
(I am willing to change my opinion.)
Also you can experiment here: https://godbolt.org/z/EdP7KzzqM

NOTE: Are there cases where the unary out-of-place operation is faster than an in-place (if both exists and both are practical)? I couldn't find many examples.
The fact that in-place operation has an initial advantage edge is the reason we tend to use mutation our programs.
One case I found is that of FFT, which maybe marginal.
Using the library FFTW I found that out-of-place FFT is a bit faster (-10%) than in-place FFT but, in turn, in-place FFT is faster than allocation plus out-of-place (+10%)!

```
timing(FFT(in, out)) < timing(FFT(io, io)) < timing(out-allocation + FFT(in, out))
```

(for example, 4 seconds, 5 seconds, 6 seconds on some of the timing with GB size data).
I don't know how much this is an artifact of the library implementation.
Unfortunately to exploit the situation fully one has to mess with the constructor itself in my experiments.